# Type checking the API response in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I'm curious what happens when you expect a certain type as a response from fetch / Axios / etc and its response is of a different type. Can i detect that mismatch?

```
interface HttpResponse<T> extends Response {
  parsedBody?: T;
}
export async function http<T>( request: RequestInfo ): Promise<HttpResponse<T>> {
  const response: HttpResponse<T> = await fetch( request );
  response.parsedBody = await response.json();
  return response;
}

// example consuming code
const response = await http<number>(
  "https://thisURLdoesNotReturnANumber"
);
```

Will the code throw an error? Will it pass silently? How do i detect a mismatch?

Comment: The API call will happen at runtime after types have been erased, so if there's a mismatch you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: If you want to do runtime type validation you need to use some ad-hoc library, like io-ts

Comment: A very good question. Sadly the answers are right and show how far behind web development (thanks to JS) is when it comes to type-safety, and therefore development in general; no runtime typing - that's half the power of static typing, and it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **typescript** code traspiles to **javascript** before browsers execute it.
It will look something like this:

```js
export async function http( request ) {
  const response = await fetch( request );
  response.parsedBody = await response.json();
  return response;
}
const response = await http("https://thisURLdoesNotReturnANumber");
```

No types, as you can see. Browsers know nothing about types defined in typescript.

Later on you may or may not get a runtime error. To throw as early as possible you need to implement a runtime check by youself inside you `http<T>()` function.
Or you can use a third-party library to do the job. There are plenty of them out there.

Comment: Do you mind giving an example on how a proposed check might look like?

Comment: @Ndrslmpk you can simply add something like `validate(response.parsedBody, constraints)` before `return response;`. What `validate` means - up to you. As an option it can be something like https://validatejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Your Typescript code will be parsed to Javascript, so at runtime, when the different type arrives from your api, the type-check is not available anymore.

You won't get any errors.

TypeScript is just a very good help at developing, but sadly, it won't fail on runtime type validations.